# Struts2 - Annotation for having multiple action methods

Tags: struts2

Within in same action class, struts2 supports multiple action methods.

One sample of struts.xml - How to convert it to annotation ?

```
 <action name="import"
    class="com.action.MainAction" method="importFiles">
    <result name="success">main.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="resourceRowAction"
    class="com.action.MainAction" method="resourceRowAction">
    <result name="success">main.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">erro.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotation solution for above Dynamic Method Invocation can be found here :

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Actionannotation

In Action:

```
@Action(value="default")
@Override
public String execute()
{
   return SUCCESS;
}

@Action(value="import")
     public String importFiles()
     {
         return SUCCESS;
     }

@Action(value="resourceRowAction")
     public String resourceRowAction()
     {
         return SUCCESS;
     }
```